# need to get rid of strange symbols in text

Tags: vi

I need to process the following text to get rid of the strange symbols such as:

`â<80><99>   â<80><9c>  â<80>?`

Example text:

> With the mystery unexplained, the Hyatt tried to give its guests a sense of security by posting a guard in its lobby. But Wolf couldnâ<80><99>t shake the notion that a thief could re-enter her room at any time. â<80><9c>I had dreams about it for many nights,â<80>?says Wolf, a 66-year-old Dell IT services consultant traveling in Houston for business.

Can anyone help me with it? I hope to either manually delete it with some command in Vi or do it with script.

Comment: Looks like you're editing a UTF-8 file in a vi that doesn't understand UTF-8, try using vim instead.

Comment: You may need to change the language support to `UTF-8` available in Window Preferences of application you are using.

Comment: @muistooshort vi became vim at least 25 years ago.

Comment: @Shiplu `vim` was only publicly released 21 years ago. Some OSes still use `vi` as default (IIRC, this includes FreeBSD). It's a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found the text in question here: http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/11/26/security-flaw-in-common-keycard-locks-exploited-in-string-of-hotel-room-break-ins/

The characters causing the problem are fancy quotes and an apostrophe, that are not the  standard ascii symbols for quotes and apostrophe.

I pasted that text into my copy of vim, and it handled those characters just fine.

But here's how to do replaces when this kind of thing happens: http://aditya.sublucid.com/2008/01/18/replacing-those-pesky-smart-quotes-in-vim/

Comment: Many thanks! It works and is just what I need.  I didn't intend to inspire any interest in the text content though.  Lesson learned :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this issue will occur if you transfer your file from Windows or DOS machines. To get rid of those unwanted special character use "dos2unix" utility

```
mkannan@talksense-dr:~/tmp$ dos2unix test.sh 
dos2unix: converting file test.sh to UNIX format ...
```

Comment: `dos2unix` converts line endings (from `CR` + `LF` to just `LF`). This looks more like a problem with the encoding of quotes. (@querystack confirmed in a comment on the other answer that it is an issue with 'smart quotes', which are not part of the ASCII character set.)